# Javascript assign function to multiple vars

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
var httpPage = new XMLHttpRequest();

function getContent(url){
  if($(".bd").css("height").replace("px", "") < $(window).height())
    $("#td_1").css("height", ($(window).height() - 167)+"px");
  httpPage.open("GET", "js_api.php?key="+(readCookie("user") || $("input[name='key']").val())+url, true);
  httpPage.send(null);
}

httpPage.onload = function(){
  //DO THINGS
}
```

Now, this code works fine for a single request. But if I send 2 request (call the function twice, but with different `url`), the first request won't execute the `httpPage.onload = function()` cause of the second request overwriting it. How can I solve it?

Comment: you need to create a new request for every getContent call

Comment: @ArunPJohny How can I do this dynamically? Can I use an array or something like this?

Comment: `function getContent(url) {
    var httpPage = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if ($(".bd").css("height").replace("px", "") < $(window).height()) {
        $("#td_1").css("height", ($(window).height() - 167) + "px");
    }
    httpPage.open("GET", "js_api.php?key=" + (readCookie("user") || $("input[name='key']").val()) + url, true);
    httpPage.send(null);

    httpPage.onload = function () {
        //DO THINGS
    }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-arrange things so that each invocation of your function gets its own local vars:

```
function getContent(url){
  var httpPage = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if($(".bd").css("height").replace("px", "") < $(window).height())
    $("#td_1").css("height", ($(window).height() - 167)+"px");
  httpPage.open("GET", "js_api.php?key="+(readCookie("user") || $("input[name='key']").val())+url, true);
  httpPage.send(null);

  httpPage.onload = function(){
    //DO THINGS
  }
}
```

Then here is an updated function that will work, passing in a function

```
function getContent(url, onload){
  var httpPage = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if($(".bd").css("height").replace("px", "") < $(window).height())
    $("#td_1").css("height", ($(window).height() - 167)+"px");
  httpPage.open("GET", "js_api.php?key="+(readCookie("user") || $("input[name='key']").val())+url, true);
  httpPage.send(null);

  httpPage.onload = onload
}

function getContent("http://invalid.com", function(data) {
  alert("DO THINGS with" + data);
});
```

Comment: I can't put `httpPage.onload = function()` inside the function because it changes everytime...

Comment: In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects.  That means that you can pass them around, stuff them in arrays and do anything else you wish to with them.  It makes the language INCREDIBLY expressive and well worth learning.